# how can i query where clause using between date in sphinx

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

I have this query:

```
select * from tabel where last_purchase_categories = 'flight' 
 and last_purchase_date between '2016-10-23 11:06:47' and '2016-10-23 11:06:49';
```

it is didnt work in sphinx. i use fulltext search using mysql query browser.
do anyone know how to using date format in sphinx ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

let's try this

it will work.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `tabel` 
where last_purchase_categories = 'flight' and 
    last_purchase_date between '2017-03-27 02:13:11' and '2017-03-27 02:13:20'
```

Comment: I can't find any difference between your query and his except the select part !!!

Answer (score 1):

Well sphinx can't do string comparisons like that, at least with between (assuming you have the date in a string attribute). And there isnt a 'datetime' **attribute** type either.

Can put the date in simple numeric attribute, and do comparisons on that.

a Unix Timestamp might be convenient, can do it in the sphinx config file (using the mysql `unix_timestamp()` function)

```
sql_query = SELECT ..., UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_purchase_date) AS last_purchase_date FROM ... 
sql_attr_uint = last_purchase_date
```

Then query would be something like

```
select * from tabel where last_purchase_categories = 'flight' 
 and last_purchase_date between 1477217207 and 1477217209;
```

Most programming language have convenient functions for converting dates to a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because data type of last_purchase_date is string. thats why i cant use between query